# How to display database stored images in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want to retrieve images from database an display them in webpage directly, how can I make a path?
Here's my view

```html
@foreach($dw as $ad)
<!-- single product -->
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">
    <div class="single-product">
        {{-- {{$ad->image}} --}}
        <img class="img-fluid" src="{{($ad->image)}}" alt="">
        <div class="product-details">
            <h5>{{$ad->jobC}}</h5>
            <div class="price">
                <h6>{{$ad->jobtype}}</h6>
                <p>{{$ad->details}}</p>
            </div>
            <div class="prd-bottom"><a href="submitcv.html">Send Your CV</a></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endforeach
```

`Controller Method`

```php
public function jaa(Request $request)
{ 
    $de = diligent::all();
    $de->image = $request->image;
    return view('jobs')->with('dw', $de);
}
```

How can I display the image? I tried this and it only shows the file name

Comment: What is stored in your database? What does `$ad->image` contain, only the filename? Then just prepend the path to where the actual image is stored.

Comment: i stored image file in database

Comment: "_i stored image file in database_" You mean the complete "contents" of the image? Like in a blob field?

Comment: yes a blob field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

asset() - Generate a URL to an application asset.

```
<img class="img-fluid" src="{{ asset('images/' . $ad->image) }}" />
```